# If statements to find age in a list

Tags: python, list, file, if-statement, input

I have made three inputs (firstname, surname and age) and put them into a file. The last part is to use this information to print out the inputs of someone if the age is above 18. I have tried using a dictionary but I did it wrong somehow. Can I use a list or a file? What can I do in order to use an if statement using that age to find out whether the details should be printed or not. Sample below.

```
def details():
    c = input('Press 1 to enter details, press 2 to browse users or press 3 to check age')
    if c == '1':
        firstname = input('Please enter your firstname')
        surname = input('Please enter your surname')
        age = input('Please enter your age')
        myfile=open('details.txt', 'at')
        myfile.write(firstname + '\n')
        myfile.write(surname + '\n')
        myfile.write(age + '\n')
        myfile.close()
        detail2 = {'Fname': firstname, 'Sname': surname, 'Age': age}
        details()
    elif c == '2':
        detail2 = {'Fname': firstname, 'Sname': surname, 'Age': age}
        read()
    elif c == '3':
        detail2 = {'Fname': firstname, 'Sname': surname, 'Age': age}
        read18()
    else:
        details()
def read():
    myfile=open('details.txt', 'rt')
    x = myfile.read()
    print(x)
def read18():
    for item in detail2:
        if Age> 18:
            print('Over 18') 
        elif Age< 18:
            print('Under 18')
"""I need to know what to do so this will print the details. Just using over or under 18 as a starting point"""

details()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the local variable detail2 within read18() where it is out of scope. You might want to open the file and read in the existing details to evaluate your 'if' loop conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think your code could use some improvements.

1. If you keep calling details(), you will eventualy hit the limit of the max recursions allowed. For that you can just put your code into `while True:` cycle and call break to break it
2. `input()` returns a string, but age is usually a number *(integer)*, so it is good practise to convert your string into integer using `int()`. You can use it directly on the `input()` -> `age = int(input('Please enter your age: '))`
3. Since you have a *list* of users, you should use *list* to keep track of them. If every user has firstname, surname and age, you call use a dictionary to keep data of every user and then add this dictionay to your list of all users
4. For writing/reading files, Python has an inbuilt `with` statement, that will take care of closing the file for you
5. If you want to quickly save a list/dictionary, you can use JSON

If you will use all of these advices, you can get code similar to this:

```
import json

FILE_SAVEFILE = "details.json"

list_persons = []  # list with user's data

def data_save():
    """
    Saves user's data into FILE_SAVEFILE
    """
    with open(FILE_SAVEFILE, 'wt') as f:
        json.dump(list_persons, f)

def data_load():
    """
    Loads data into list_persons from FILE_SAVEFILE
    """
    global list_persons
    with open(FILE_SAVEFILE, 'rt') as f:
        list_persons = json.load(f)

while True:
    c = input('Press 1 to enter details, press 2 to browse users or press 3 to check age: ')
    if c == "1":
        new_person_data = {
            "firstname": input('Please enter your firstname: '),
            "surname": input('Please enter your surname: '),
            "age": int(input('Please enter your age: ')),
        }
        list_persons.append(new_person_data)
        data_save()
        continue
    if c == "2":
        data_load()
        for dict_user in list_persons:
            print('Firstname: ' + dict_user["firstname"])
            print('Surname: ' + dict_user["surname"])
            print('Age: ' + str(dict_user["age"]))
        continue
    if c == "3":
        for dict_user in list_persons:
            str_agestr = " is over 18" if dict_user["age"] > 18 else " is under 18"
            print(dict_user["firstname"] + " " + dict_user["surname"] + str_agestr)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many improvements that could be made to your code, indeed the answer from E. Aho uses a few of them but they may be a tad confusing if you are new to python.
Mildly adapting your code and adding a few comments:

```
def details():
    c = input('Press 1 to enter details, press 2 to browse users or press 3 to check age: ')
    if c == '1':
        firstname = input('Please enter your firstname: ')
        surname = input('Please enter your surname: ')
        age = input('Please enter your age: ')
        myfile=open('details.txt', 'at')

        # write data as a single record

        myfile.write(firstname + ',' + surname + ',' + age + '\n')
        myfile.close()
        details()

    elif c == '2':
        read()
    elif c == '3':
        read18()
    else:
        details()

def read():
    myfile=open('details.txt', 'r')

    # read file line by line

    x = myfile.readlines()
    for item in x:
        print (item.strip()) #Strip newline
    myfile.close()

def read18():
    myfile=open('details.txt', 'r')
    x = myfile.readlines()
    for item in x:

        # split each line into component parts, splitting on comma separator and strip newline

        firstname,surname,age = item.strip().split(',')
        detail2 = {'Fname': firstname, 'Sname': surname, 'Age': int(age)}
        if detail2['Age'] > 17:
            print('Over 18 via Dict')
        else:
            print('Under 18 via Dict')

        # or dispense with the dictionary

        if int(age) > 17:
            print(firstname,surname,'at',age,'is 18 or over')
        else:
            print(firstname,surname,'at',age,'is under 18')
    myfile.close()
"""I need to know what to do so this will print the details. Just using over or under 18 as a starting point"""

details()
```

Comment: Each time I try to browse users it comes up with the error message and at the bottom says "age is not defined". Even when I add a user first then browse users, the error message is the same. Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: I assume that you have made an error somewhere because the browse function `read()` does not reference the variable `age` it only prints `item`